# How do I install the LSI megacli in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, raid

Similar to this question (https://serverfault.com/questions/192394/megacli-always-returns-blank-output) with some differences.

I am using perc h710p raid controller on Dell Ubuntu box.

I downloaded `1.01.39_Linux_Cli.zip` (according to https://calomel.org/megacli_lsi_commands.html) and saved `MegaCli64` on Ubuntu usb boot drive.

Then I boot the machine into USB, and run `MegaCli64`.

But the output is always blank.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Why dont you get the latest megacli downloaded from the LSI site? Plus you need more than just the executable, the zip file you get the contains the program is a deb package that you need to install in to your system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its returning empty because you are running the executable without the libraries.

To install it correctly go the the LSI download site and search for [`megacli`](https://www.broadcom.com/site-search?q=megacli).

Download the latest version (release 8.07):

[image]

Extract it via a gui or with the command `unzip MegaCli_Linux.zip`.

Install the extracted .deb file with `dpkg -i megacli_8.07.08-1_all.deb` or just double click the deb file if you are running a desktop.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. BTW, is there a way to run megacli through rescue usb drive?

Comment: There was no .deb file in my downloaded archive, so I used `alien  MegaCli-8.07.14-1.noarch.rpm` to get that.

Comment: To add onto @flob's answer, this method of installation is officially documented in Broadcom's knowledge base (ID 1211161500661) here: https://www.broadcom.com/support/knowledgebase/1211161500661/installing-megacli-in-debian-or-ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

- download MegaCLI package for Ubuntu:

  ```
  wget http://hwraid.le-vert.net/debian/pool-stretch/megacli/megacli_8.07.14-2%2BDebian.stretch.9.9_amd64.deb
  ```
- install MegaCLI in your system:

  ```
  dpkg -i megacli_8.07.14-2%2BDebian.stretch.9.9_amd64.deb
  ```
- update your repositories:

  ```
  apt-get update
  ```
- check info about your RAID controller:

  ```
  megacli -LDInfo -LAll -aAll
  ```

Comment: I think your `curl` should be a `wget`.

Comment: You couldn't download this file with curl?

Comment: Yes, I can download with curl but not as it's written. `curl` sends to stdout by default. If you want to use `curl` then you should specify an output file with `curl -o output_file url`. `wget` default is to create a file of the same name as the file you are retrieving, which would work like you have it. Either program would work. And, btw, this was exactly the solution I was looking for. Saved me from having to slog through this in bios.

Answer (score 2):

`storcli64`, referenced in [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/718697/141998) worked for me:

```
$ sudo storcli64 /c0/d0 show
Controller = 0
Status = Success
Description = Show Diskgroup Succeeded

TOPOLOGY :
========
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT      Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 -   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  N  10.913 TB enbl N  N   none N      
 0 0   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  N  10.913 TB enbl N  N   none N      
 0 0   0   252:0    3   DRIVE Onln  N   3.638 TB enbl N  N   none -      
 0 0   1   252:1    2   DRIVE Onln  N   3.638 TB enbl N  N   none -      
 0 0   2   252:2    1   DRIVE Onln  N   3.638 TB enbl N  N   none -      
 0 0   3   252:3    0   DRIVE Onln  N   3.638 TB enbl N  N   none -      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the documentation and download page: [StorCLI](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/StorCLI).

Answer (score 0):

To search for utility from LSI use [this link](https://www.broadcom.com/site-search?q=megacli) (as of Mar 2019).

Comment: This is a duplicate of the link in the accepted answer.