# Ubuntu 16 installation - Raid disks are not getting detected on Lenovo ThinkSystem SR630

Tags: system-installation

We have recently bought Lenovo ThinkSystem SR630.

We had created an Raid 1 Volume from the UEFI setup. However during the installation of Ubuntu 16, the virtual disks are not getting detected. This system carries ThinkSystem RAID 930-8i 2GB Flash PCIe 12Gb Adapter.

Lenovo doesn't have any Ubuntu drivers for SR630 model.

Request your support.

Comment: How many drives do you see ? If there are no drivers for the hardware RAID, use software raid, AKA mdadm - https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html#software-raid and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: software raid is preferred due to the quirky and often unavailable drivers for hardware raid

Comment: There are 2 disks which hardware Raid can see. I have configured Raid 1. However Ubuntu fails to recognise those virtual volumes during installation.

Comment: As I said, if Ubuntu does not recognize your hardware raid, turn it off in your bios and use software raid, ie mdadm, see the links I gave you.

Comment: There is no option to turn off the raid on the bios, This disks have to be configured as part of Raid for installation .... We just need Ubuntu to detect this disks during the install. Please note that ubuntu has certified Lenovo Thinksystem SR630 as per their website

Comment: apparently your raid controller uses megaraid . The only thing I found regarding kernel modules is a bug report on centos - https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=12601&nbn=14 . This bug report is recent and includes patches for the Centos kernel ( 3.10) . Nothing on kernel.org. I suggest you file a bug report with Ubuntu and link to the Centos bug or perhaps kernel.org.

Comment: For megaraid see http://www.queryadmin.com/1620/install-megacli-debian-packages-lsi-megaraid-sas/ and https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Hardware_Raid_Setup_using_MegaCli . There is also this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/488612/how-do-i-install-the-lsi-megacli-in-ubuntu but the debian packages from the first link worked for me (on a different controller)

Comment: here is my personal cheat sheet with some links - http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/megacli/